# Scheduling container in Azure

Tags: python, azure, docker, cloud

I would like to know if it is possible to schedule a docker container task (start) in Azure so it could be executed automatically once per week.

Thank you.

Comment: Please refer [Docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 1):

There is [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-scheduled) in microsoft page for this.

In short, you can do this by azure cli:

```
az acr task timer add \
  --name timertask \
  --registry $ACR_NAME \
  --timer-name timer2 \
  --schedule "30 10 * * *"
```